# Bounding Box Collision Glitching Problem (Pygame)

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame, grid

So far the "Bounding Box" method is the only one that I know. It's efficient enough to deal with simple games. Nevertheless, the game I'm developing is not that simple anymore and for that reason, I've made a simplified example of the problem. (It's worth noticing that I don't have rotating sprites on my game or anything like that. After showing the code, I'll explain better).

**Here's the whole code:**

```
from pygame import *

DONE = False
screen = display.set_mode((1024,768))
class Thing():
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,s,c):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.s = s
        self.sur = Surface((64,48))
        draw.rect(self.sur,c,(self.x,self.y,w,h),1)
        self.sur.fill(c)
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.sur,(self.x,self.y))
    def move(self,x):
        if key.get_pressed()[K_w] or key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            if x == 1:
                self.y -= self.s
            else:
                self.y += self.s
        if key.get_pressed()[K_s] or key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            if x == 1:
                self.y += self.s
            else:
                self.y -= self.s
        if key.get_pressed()[K_a] or key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
            if x == 1:
                self.x -= self.s
            else:
                self.x += self.s
        if key.get_pressed()[K_d] or key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
            if x == 1:
                self.x += self.s
            else:
                self.x -= self.s
    def warp(self):
        if self.y < -48:
             self.y = 768
        if self.y > 768 + 48:
             self.y = 0
        if self.x < -64:
             self.x = 1024 + 64
        if self.x > 1024 + 64:
             self.x = -64
r1 = Thing(0,0,64,48,1,(0,255,0))
r2 = Thing(6*64,6*48,64,48,1,(255,0,0))
while not DONE:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    r2.draw()
    r1.draw()
    # If not intersecting, then moves, else, it moves in the opposite direction.
    if not ((((r1.x + r1.w) > (r2.x - r1.s)) and (r1.x < ((r2.x + r2.w) + r1.s))) and (((r1.y + r1.h) > (r2.y - r1.s)) and (r1.y < ((r2.y + r2.h) + r1.s)))):
        r1.move(1)
    else:
        r1.move(0)
    r1.warp()
    if key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
        DONE = True
    for ev in event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            DONE = True
    display.update()
quit()
```

**The problem:**

In my actual game, the grid is fixed and each tile has 64 by 48 pixels. I know how to deal with collision perfectly if I moved by that size. Nevertheless, obviously, the player moves really fast.

In the example, the collision is detected pretty well (Just as I see in many examples throughout the internet). The problem is that if I put the player to move WHEN IS NOT intersecting, then, when it touches the obstacle, it does not move anymore. Giving that problem, I began switching the directions, but then, when it touches and I press the opposite key, it "glitches through". My actual game has many walls, and the player will touch them many times, and I can't afford letting the player go through them.

**The code-problem illustrated:**

When the player goes towards the wall (Fine).

[image]

When the player goes towards the wall and press the opposite direction. (It glitches through).

[image]

Here is the logic I've designed before implementing it:

[image]

I don't know any other method, and I really just want to have walls fixed in a grid, but move by 1 or 2 or 3 pixels (Slowly) and have perfect collision without glitching-possibilities. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are hitting right on the border and are not checking for that.

```
# if collision move opposite else move forward
if  ((((r1.x + r1.w) >= (r2.x - r1.s)) && (r1.x <= ((r2.x + r2.w) + r1.s))) && (((r1.y + r1.h) >= (r2.y - r1.s)) && (r1.y <= ((r2.y + r2.h) + r1.s)))):
    r1.move(0)
else:
    r1.move(1)
```

Also I think there are a couple of errors in your `warp()`. I think it should read:

```
def warp(self):
    if self.y < -48:
         self.y = 768
    if self.y > 768 + 48:
         self.y = 0
    if self.x < -64:
         self.x = 1024    <----- here
    if self.x > 1024 + 64:
         self.x = 0     <------ and here
```